# Best practice for Zend 2 FieldSets, re-use them or re-create them for every specific situation?

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Me and my colleague were arguing about whether or not we should re-use certain Zend2 FieldSet classes in our project.
Using the framework we create many different forms, and there are quite a few forms for which the same information needs to be filled in.
For example, we have a form to create a new employee and a form to create a new contactperson. For both forms, contact information needs to be filled in, so both forms add an AccountFieldSet to the form.

Now currently, for every new form, a new AccountFieldSet is created so we have Customer\Form\Contact\AccountFieldset and Employee\Form\AccountFieldSet which both contain code like:

```
<?php
namespace Employee\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;
use OurProject\Entity\Account;

class AccountFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $oObjectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('account');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($oObjectManager))->setObject(new Account());

        $oAccountAddressFieldset = new AccountAddressFieldset($oObjectManager);
        $this->add($oAccountAddressFieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'listGender',
            'options' => array(
                'empty_option' => '',
                'object_manager' => $oObjectManager,
                'target_class' => 'OurProject\Entity\ListGender',
                'property' => 'name'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'select2',
                'data-placeholder' => 'Gender'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name' => 'firstname',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control input-xs',
                'placeholder' => 'First name',
                'required' => 'required'
            )
        ));
```

My colleague argues that this is the correct way to go, because there are also forms for which not every field of the Contact should appear, and re-using that FieldSet would then give extra overhead by loading more info then necessary.

I in turn believe that have two classes with (almost) the same code is always bad practice and that therefore we should re-use the same class, and only create a new one when there are in fact differences. This way we do not have the same code at different places, which should reduce the amount of places where we should change code if changes should occur.

Alternatively, I suggested there should be a base class with the minimal FieldSet called BaseContactFieldSet that contains all fields that will always be used by all forms, and that that other FieldSet classes should extend upon that class and add any input elements that are not in the BaseContactFieldSet.

My colleague believes that there are too many exceptions for every form and that therefore it is necessary to just create a lot of duplicate code in different places, and that we should not re-use FieldSet classes at all to prevent creating code to handle exceptions.

So we were wondering what others think. Should we re-use as many code as we can, or should we create duplicate code because there may be exceptions for specific forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is a DRY approach (Don't Repeat Yourself) rather then a WET approach (Write Everything Twice).

Add the common elements to the AccountFieldset (consider an abstract class here) and then extend it using EmployeeAccountFieldset and CustomerAccountFieldset.

Register the concrete fieldset classes with the FormElementManager Service and you can then access the fieldset objects from anywhere you have access to the serviceManager, they will be lazy-loaded so if you don't call the service they will never get instantiated.

in your module config:

```
return [  
        'form_elements' => [
                'invokables'=>[
    'MyNameSpace\Form\Fieldset\EmployeeAccount'=>'MyNameSpace\Form\Fieldset\EmployeeAccountFieldset'
]]];
```

You can also then tweak the fieldsetObjects (rather than the class itself) if you need to add/remove certain elements for specific usages.

```
        //get fieldset object via the FormElementManager ServiceManager
        $employeeAccountFieldset=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('MyNameSpace\Form\Fieldset\EmployeeAccount');

        //remove password element
        $employeeAccountFieldset->remove('password');

        //tweak an element
        $employeeAccountFieldset->get('email')->setAttribute('class','myCSSClass');

        //add tweaked fieldset to form
        $myFormObject->add($employeeAccountFieldset);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with the DRY v.s. WET approach. My colleague is, unfortunately, still not convinced though, but I guess that takes much more answers, which I don't see happening anytime soon.